# Google App Script as public gateway for database (spreadsheet)

Tags: authentication, penetration-test, http, android

I've created a google app script that takes a `POST` request and writes to a google spreadsheet. In parallel, I've also made an Android app that sends `HTTP` requests to this google app script.

I did it like this because my company didn't want to buy a server to store data. Now I'm worried about security issues. For example, if a user sniffs the network or reverse engineers my app, he can

1. Get the `URL` of the script
2. And the parameters required in the `POST` request

So am I screwed? Or are there some tricks that I can do to make people waste their time in the hacking process?

---

**NOTE** - I do not have a server available/at my disposal merely the script I've written.

Answer (score 1):

Any user can extract the parameters and send the scripts yes. Unless you have a method to authenticate users and sanitize input server side anyone can post anything to your script.

Depending on how you have published your script you may be able to use googles authentication system here. You could force the user to be logged in with a valid google account to be able to post, recording the changes against their username. If required you could also lock execution to only pre-approved google accounts.

Alternatively a small VPS (EC2 or similar) instance hosting a web front end and a database would be ~$10 USD per month. I'd suggest you make your employer aware this would make the system far more flexible, secure and scalable. I'd imagine compared to your annual salary this is a negligible cost.